# How far away from artificial light do you need to get to experience the night sky without light polution?

Tags: nature-and-wildlife

Twice this week I stumbled upon an article mentioning phenemenons visible with the naked eye if no artificial light is near by. The first [was a series of meteorites](https://www.facebook.com/IFeakingLoveScience/photos/a.456449604376056.98921.367116489976035/791226314231715/?type=1), the second [a photo experiment on how the night sky would look without artificial light](https://www.facebook.com/IFeakingLoveScience/photos/a.456449604376056.98921.367116489976035/796854660335547/?type=1).

[image: cities withou light here]

The question is how far I need to travel away from a well lit city or road to experience such beautiful skys?

Comment: Also note, that while you can see a lot more stars far away from light pollution, you might not see them in such detail as in some of the pictures above. I would estimate that pictures like the Sao Paulo one or the Rio de Janeiro one with all the colourful areas are only visible through photography even in total absence of light. Often times when you see those pretty star panoramas, you couldn't see them with your naked eye, as the human eye is not sensitive enough for that.

Comment: @drat links added

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about photography. It's far to broad as a travel question since the answer would be completely different depending on where you are.

Comment: @uncovery it is by far about photography. Tbh I don't care about making pictures. I would really like to watch a starry sky without light pollution. But even it was about photography, why wouldn't it fit this QA site. A photographer might be interested in knowing how far he needs to TRAVEL(!!) to make these pictures.

Comment: All I need to do to see the sky with no light pollution is to get home. :)

Comment: Try [Astronomy.SE](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) or [Photography.SE](http://photo.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think this question is completely on-topic on Travel, as seeing the night sky is a very valid tourism/travel reason.  I don't see why it would depend on where you are.  I don't understand the close votes at all.

Comment: The question is unanswerable because it depends on too many variables. A big city generates more light than a small one. A sprawling city generates more light than a dense one. The wet, dense atmosphere of a coastal city reflects and scatters more light than the dry, thin air of a city in the mountains. Cities with HPS streetlights emit less light than those with mercury vapor lamps; those with LEDs even less. It's impossible to say "drive an hour" or "drive 100km" as a general rule; it's best to consult local amateur astronomy clubs for stargazing spots.

Comment: @gerrit I think this type of question is also on-topic, but this one is too broad. As stated in other comments, it is very difficult to answer it in general. Area specific is, in my opinion, highly on-topic here.

Comment: For North America, you can find dark spots [through this interactive web applet](http://www.jshine.net/astronomy/dark_sky/).

Comment: @choster I don't see why your comment can be a starting point for a great answer. Quite some travelbooks, articles or blogs often state that you need to get away from light pollution to enjoy a starry night, but how far do you need to get to have no pollution. You seems quite knowledgeable here.

Comment: @Bernhard But then you need to ask a ton of questions if you are interested in stargazing. "How far do I need to travel from new york/London/Amsterdam/Albina/Ouzoud/.....". I indeed can ask my local astronomy club, but then I need to ask next to all these stargazing questions, also a question per area how I find a local astronomy group. Choster already started with quite an answer, there must be quite some knowledgeable people out there that can give similar advise.

Comment: @andra But wouldn't that be on a similar basis on question about "How to get from A to B"? Of course you can give a general answer, but specifics concerning A or B make it much more answerable. This is somehow similar in my opinion.

Comment: @gerrit: Photography is also an incredibly popular Tourist activity. That doesn't mean asking about the proper aperture to achieve the desired bokeh is on-topic here, even if you are photographing the Taj Mahal.

Comment: @Flimzy [this meta answer disagrees](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/1303/2509), and states that travel activities are on-topic.  We have plenty of questions on hiking in spot X (also on-topic on The Great Outdoors), nightlife in spot Y, museums in spot Z, etc. — all popular tourist activities.  I think this question fits in the same category, as would travel-specific photography questions.  Either they're all on-topic, or they're all off-topic.  We may continue this discussion [on meta](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/1299/2509).

Comment: @gerrit: That meta answer says nothing about the technical aspects of photography. I'm certain that how to achieve a desired bokeh at the Taj Mahal would be closed immediately here.

Comment: Even if this question is deemed on-topic, it's still far too broad. And it would still get better answers at Astronomy.SE.

Comment: Interesting related picture: https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1.0-9/10168012_798813333473013_8363697636346594388_n.jpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure this answers your question but here it goes:

If you travel into the sea at night you will be able to find the most beautifull sky. From my experience, being around 15 miles offcoast should already give you a very nice sky panorama.

Another option is finding a dark sky reserve. It's just like a natural reserve but applied to the sky. Some criteria has to be met for this. In Portugal, Alentejo you can find such a dark sky reserve. It was the first spot on earth receiving the “Starlight Tourism Destination Certification” given by the starlight foundations and supported by Unesco. [More information in portuguese can be found here](http://www.turismodeportugal.pt/Portugu%C3%AAs/AreasAtividade/desenvolvimentoeinovacao/Pages/ReservaDarkSkyAlqueva.aspx). Meanwhile I found [the official? website here](http://www.darkskyalqueva.com/). They provide an english version.

It's intersting to check the criteria to have such certification:

- Clouds: > 50% nights withoug clouds (Dark Sky Alqueva Reserve has more than 286 nights
- without clouds)
- Darkness: > 21mag/arcsec² (Dark Sky Alqueva Reserve has 21,60 mag/arcsec²)
- Vision: ≤ 2"
- Transparency: mag 6

[image: Alentejo night sky]

A quick google search also showed that England recently created a similar reserve in Northumberland county.

Comment: This is also a little bit helpful in finding dark spots: http://www.nightlightmap.com/

Comment: More information on the site of [International Dark-sky Association](http://www.darksky.org) (IDA), which is the recognized authority on light pollution.

Answer (score 4):

Answer isn't clear cut. A lot depends on atmospheric conditions, as well as geography and the direction you're looking.
If there's cloud cover, those city lights can be seen a long way away indeed, it can make the clouds over the place glow (ever more yellow or orange because of the sodium lights used for streetlighting in ever more cities).
If the city is on a hilltop between you and where you're looking at, it's also going to be much more visible then if it were in a depression in the terrain and hidden from direct view.
And a city close by can influence your view even when looking away from it (especially if there's some thin clouds...).
As stated in the comments, size of the city matters a lot. As does the level of technology and prosperity.
Seoul or Tokyo are going to cause a lot more light pollution than do Pyong Yang or Harrare for example.
And don't forget that nice area of greenhouses on the edge of town, they're like beacons in the night. Same with the prison, and the oil refinery with its floodlights on the security perimiter.