# Is there a resource that lists dark sky reserves or similar places?

Tags: online-resources, planning, nature-and-wildlife

After reading this [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26262/how-far-away-from-artificial-light-do-you-need-to-get-to-experience-the-night-sk) I started wondering if there is a resource that lists good places to observe the night sky. Places with good sky visibility and litle light polution. Is there such a resource?

Comment: See my comment to your own answer there: More information on the site of [International Dark-sky Association](http://www.darksky.org) (IDA), which is the recognized authority on light pollution

Answer (score 6):

There's a [list of IDA-certified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Dark-Sky_Association#International_Dark_Sky_Parks) [dark sky reserves](http://www.darksky.org/night-sky-conservation/dark-sky-parks).

Wikipedia has [a more comprehensive list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark-sky_preserve), that includes nationally declared areas that may not be certified by IDA.